# How to create one page website without plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Recently my boss bought a Wordpress theme called "X",http://theme.co/x/. In this theme, it can archive one page website with the navigation bar fixed at the top of browser.But my boss want the navigation bar at the right side. I've searched online and found out some plugins can archive this effect.But the theme support team says that they are not responsible for any problems caused by third-part plugin.

So I want to ask is that possible to change the navigation style directly changing back-end code instead of using plugins?If I can,how?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you move it with CSS?

Comment: you are gonna have to change the theme code.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a backup-copy of each file you are going to change
**NOTE THAT THERE MIGHT BE SLIGHT DIFFERENCES IN LINE NUMBERS**

**STEP 1**
find

```
.x-navbar-fixed-top-active .x-navbar-wrap {height: 54px;}
```

as an style in your index file and change it to:

```
.x-navbar-fixed-top-active .x-navbar-wrap {width: 88px;}
```

also find

```
.x-navbar-inner {min-height: 54px;}
```

as an style in your index file and change it to:

```
..x-navbar-inner {min-width: 88px;}
```

88px is width of each menu item, you may adjust it to fit your exact needed value by yourself.

**STEP 2**
find `x-custom.css`, make sure it is not minified and open it using notepad++ (or any other semi-advanced code editor) at least, as you will need to trace line numbers.
Change css in `x-custom.css` as follows:

---

line 230 (.page-template-template-layout-home-1-php .x-navbar.x-navbar-fixed-top, .page-template-template-layout-home-1-lp-f-php .x-navbar.x-navbar-fixed-top) From

```
top: 0;
bottom: auto;
```

To

```
right: 0;
left: auto;
```

---

line 237 (.page-template-template-layout-home-1-php .x-navbar .x-container-fluid, .page-template-template-layout-home-1-lp-f-php .x-navbar .x-container-fluid) From

```
width: auto;
max-width: none;
```

To

```
height: auto;
max-height: none;
```

---

line 243 (.page-template-template-layout-home-1-php .x-navbar .x-nav, .page-template-template-layout-home-1-lp-f-php .x-navbar .x-nav) Remove

```
padding-left: 65px;
```

---

line 250 (.page-template-template-layout-home-1-php .x-navbar .x-nav > li, .page-template-template-layout-home-1-lp-f-php .x-navbar .x-nav > li) Remove

```
width: 10%;
```

Add

```
clear: right;
```

---

line 257 (.page-template-template-layout-home-1-php .x-navbar .x-nav > li.li-0, .page-template-template-layout-home-1-lp-f-php .x-navbar .x-nav > li.li-0) Remove

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Add

```
float:right;
```

---

line 273 (.page-template-template-layout-home-1-php .x-navbar .x-nav > li > a, .page-template-template-layout-home-1-lp-f-php .x-navbar .x-nav > li > a) From

```
border-right: 1px solid #171717;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.065);
box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.065);
```

To

```
border-top: 1px solid #171717;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.065);
box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.065);
```

**STEP 3**
find `integrity-light.css`
Change css in `integrity-light.css` as follows:

---

line 1478 Remove

```
float: left;
```

Answer (score 0):

A navigation menu in wordpress can be created and then provided as a widget option. Under appearance find menus (see link), and make the navigation menu as you want, which can include child pages and or posts. Drop the menu widget in the sidebar and select the menu you created. Then if needed, you can delete the top menu from your theme and use CSS to make your sidebar menu suit your appearance needs.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

What I don't understand is why a one page website needs navigation?

If you want one page with specific navigation that is different to a main website - look into using a page and a creating a custom page template for it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates#Custom_Page_Template